# How to keep the marked item when changing order to asc or desc

Tags: javascript, css, dom

When i mark an item and then change its order to asc or desc, the item get unmarked. I'm not sure how to keep it marked.

This is the plnkr code, you can try it here to see how it looks, https://plnkr.co/edit/bSH8A6GwRrKizFTDpfYI?p=info

```
var idxEditare = -1;
var lista = [];

function adauga(form,event){
    event.preventDefault();
        var obj = {
    };

    obj.itemDes = form.querySelector("[name='itemDes']").value;

    lista.push(obj);
    draw();
    afiseazaLista();
}

function afiseazaLista(){
    document.querySelector("#add-form").reset();
    document.querySelector("#tabel").classList.remove("hidden");
}

function ascundeLista(){
    document.querySelector("#tabel").classList.add("hidden");
}


function empty(){
    var itemInput= document.querySelector("[name='itemDes']").value;

    if(itemInput===""){
        event.preventDefault();
        (alert(`Completeaza spatiile pentru a face o adaugire in lista`));
        return false;
    }

}

function mark(ceva){
    document.querySelector(`#target-${ceva}`).classList.add("description");
}

function asc(){
    lista.sort(function(a,b){
        if(a.itemDes>b.itemDes){
            return 1;
        } else if(a.itemDes<b.itemDes){
            return -1;
        } else{
            return 0;
        }
    });
    draw();
}

function desc(){
    lista.sort(function(a,b){
        if(a.itemDes<b.itemDes){
            return 1;
        } else if(a.itemDes>b.itemDes){
            return -1;
        } else{
            return 0;
        }
    });
    draw();
}

function draw(){
    var str = "";

        for(var i=0;i<lista.length;i++){
            str+=`<tr>
                <td id="target-${i}">${lista[i].itemDes}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Mark as buyed" onClick="mark(${i});"/>
                </td>
            </tr>`;
        }
        document.querySelector("#tabel tbody").innerHTML = str;
}
```

The item should remain marked even after i change the order to asc or desc.

Comment: Made a plunkr with separate files: https://plnkr.co/edit/6akZi96CTz4siOSLKvWU?p=preview

Comment: You can either a) rearrange the table rows instead of recreating them (since this retains the class that marks the item as done or b) store the state in your array by storing objects like `{ desc: "blah", done: false }` - - The preferred solution is b) since an app should always store the entire state in dedicated variables (as opposed to the DOM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't track changes of buyed items, and each sort you redraw everything without knowledge of buyed items.

So you can save buyed items inside your mark function

```
   function mark(ceva){  
            lista[ceva].added = !lista[ceva].added;  

            if(lista[ceva].added){
            document.querySelector(`#target-${ceva}`).classList.add("description");
            } else {
            document.querySelector(`#target-${ceva}`).classList.remove("description");
            }
    }
```

Now you can add or remove buy items, based on state, and now on your draw method check it items are added. If they are added just add class.

```
function draw(){

            var str = "";

                for(var i=0;i<lista.length;i++){ 
                  var isAdded = lista[i].added ? "description" : "";
                    str+=`<tr>
                        <td id="target-${i}" class='${isAdded}'>${lista[i].itemDes}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Mark as buyed" onClick=mark(${i}); "/>
                        </td>

                    </tr>`;
                }
                document.querySelector("#tabel tbody").innerHTML = str;
        }
```

Working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/L3FrZUYds46caHXaLdFX?p=preview